# Set up paypal gateway for platforms

Tags: paypal, woocommerce

I'm trying to setup paypal as payment method for a platform like eventbrite where is only required the organizer's paypal email in order to receive payments from its guests. Or like woocommerce where is only required the seller's paypal account.

I tried to use Paypal Adaptive Payments, it was fine until I figured out that I can't show the product details like Woocommerce does... what I'm missing from Paypal docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Express Checkout, which supports parallel payments.  You just need to include the SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID parameter in the API request and set it to the email address of the account you want the money sent to.

So then you'd use your own API credentials, but you'd set that parameter to the 3rd party account you want the money to fall into.  It will work without any permissions from the 3rd party account.

There are existing plugins for Express Checkout in WooCommerce (I would recommend [PayPal for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/), which is free) but they don't yet support the use of SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID to send payments to a 3rd party account.  That said, the PayPal for WooCommerce plugin could be pretty easily customized to get that done.

As a side note, you can include itemized details with Adaptive Payments, but you have to include an additional API call, SetPaymentOptions, after getting a PayKey from the Pay API, but before redirecting the user to PayPal.  This is where you can setup shipping, tax, items, etc.

I would recommend sticking with Express Checkout, though, as the checkout experience is a lot better with it.